# How to make Firebase get data from inside push() keys?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Let's say I have this:

```
Campaigns:{
    UNIQUE_ID:{
     title: "Hello",
     description: "Desc"
  }
}
```

And a bunch of other `UNIQUE_ID`s, and I want to retrieve title and description and put them into a `RecyclerView`.

---

**What I tried:**

I tried making a custom Campaign class, with the strings `description` and `title`.

And I have this method:

```
 String title;
 String description;
 public Campaign(){}
 public Campaign(String title, String description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

When I try getting the adapter, with this method:

```
 RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Campaign,CampaignHolder>(Campaign.class, R.layout.recyclerview_template, CampaignHolder.class,ref){
        @Override
        public void  populateViewHolder(CampaignHolder viewHolder, Campaign campaign, int position){
            viewHolder.setTitle(campaign.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDescription(campaign.getDescription());
        }
    };
```

`campaign.getTitle()` is obviously returning `null`, and I can see why, since I never called on the constructor. But, if I want to call the constructor, I need the parameters `title,description`. But where do I get this, or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Campaign` class will need either setters (in addition to the getters you already have):

```
public class Campaign {
     String title;
     String description;
     public Campaign(){}
     public Campaign(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Or alternatively, just make the fields public and remove the getters/setters:

```
public class Campaign {
     public String title;
     public String description;
     public Campaign(){}
     public Campaign(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }    
}
```

Based on these public fields (or getters/setter), the Firebase Database client will automatically populate the data based on the JSON it reads from the database.

Comment: But wait, in my ViewHolder I have setters. Does it make a difference?

Comment: And, if I'm implementing your second method, do I even call on `Campaign(title,description)`?

Comment: you don't need to do anything, firebase-ui automatically map that for you and then pass it as a parameter in the `populateViewHolder()` method @AbAppletic

Comment: title is still `null` even after doing as you said

Comment: are you sure that the `ref` is pointing at `.child("Campaigns")`? And the fields' name from your model class match with the keys in your firebase database?

Comment: Thanks so much you to. I wish I could give you a hug

Comment: @Wilik I'd like to know your opinion about this question.Was it asked good? Was it too unclear? Please vote depending on how you thinl

Comment: @AbAppletic you're welcome :)
In my opinion, yeah, your question is good already. cheers